# How to get all categories in XML format from Wikipeida?

Tags: wikipedia, categories

I found some parameters for finding different information in XML here: 
[Mediawiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery_-_Lists#categorymembers_.2F_cm)

I want to get all the categories provided at the end of any article. Till now, I've found this URL to get the information about, for example, Obama, [Barack Obama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aExport/Barack_Obama)

Will I have to parse this to get a list of categories? I want categories at the bottom of each article, e.g. in case of Obama, I need the categories like: "1961 births", "African American academics" etc. How can I do that? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`prop=categories`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties#categories_.2F_cl), something like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Barack%20Obama&prop=categories&cllimit=max).